# How can I get plot line handle through mouse position/behavior in MatLab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm writing a GUI program with one axis and multiple lines in it.

Is it possible to select the lines (only lines, no other components) by mouse click/current mouse position?

I suppose to implement it like :

```
set(obj.fh,'WindowButtonDownFcn',@(src, event)mouseSelection(obj, src, event));
```

But I don't know what shall I fill in function mouseSelection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved rather simply, e.g.

```
plot(1:10, 'ButtonDownFcn', @(h,d) fprintf('my blue line\n'))
hold on
plot(10:-1:1, 'r', 'ButtonDownFcn', @(h,d) fprintf('my red line\n'))
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much :) But is it possible to return back the handle of the selected curve in callback?

Comment: The handle is the `h` (first) parameter of the callback. Do whatever you want to do with in within the callback and its callees. However values returned from selection callbacks are usually ignored, so these callbacks generally don't bother returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to operate on the high level windows. It is much simpler to operate directly at line level. 
A possible solution is to use a property listener:

```
function test

figure('HitTest','on')
axes('HitTest','on')
h = plot([1,2,3],[3,2,7],'HitTest','on');

el = addlistener(h,'Selected','PostSet',@callback);

plotedit


function callback(schema,EventData)

if strcmp(EventData.AffectedObject.Selected,'on')
    disp('OK')
end
```

This prints OK when you select the line. There are also others way such as using the `ButtonDownFunction` of the line, but the result is slightly different.